# Comparing AVG() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first SQL query practice and I came up with this problem where I have to find an average of Quantity of items in stock from somewhere house that is greater than the average of a specific warehouse. All i got is a list of the warehouse with their average (the specific warehouse is not included) and I have to keep only the warehouse with its average that is greater than the average of that specific warehouse. How do I solve this? This is my first time learning SQL. Thank you

```
SELECT Warehouse, AVG(QuantityInStocks) AS Average
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Warehouse Not In ('Specific_Warehouse')
GROUP BY Warehouse;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: I can't post image yet.

Comment: Post it as text. Before running your `SELECT`, click on `Results to Text` or press `CTRL + T`. Then copy and paste the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use subquery in HAVING clause:

```
SELECT Warehouse, AVG(QuantityInStocks) AS Average
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Warehouse NOT IN ('Specific_Warehouse')
GROUP BY Warehouse
HAVING AVG(QuantityInStocks) > 
    (SELECT AVG(QuantityInStocks) 
    FROM SomeTable 
    WHERE Warehouse IN ('Specific_Warehouse') 
    GROUP BY Warehouse);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for.  It's great to learn new thing since I haven't seen HAVING clause before.

Comment: a gratis reputation, really don't know what to say for this. author of the question told `I want an average` which can get it easily without any `having` and `group by` like [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28271591/3208640). anyway good luck.

Comment: Think of HAVING as a WHERE that applies only to the result of aggregate functions such as COUNT, SUM, AVG, etc.

Comment: @TommCatt, best ever interpretation of HAVING

Answer (score 1):

with regard to what you mentioned in question

> "I have to find an average of Quantity of items in stock from somewhere house 
>   that is greater than the average of a specific warehouse"

you can use A `NESTED SELECT` in `WHERE CLAUSE`:

```
SELECT AVG(QuantityInStocks) AS Average
FROM SomeTable
WHERE QuantityInStocks > (SELECT AVG(QuantityInStocks)
                          FROM SomeTable)
```

Comment: But in the WHERE clause, The QuantityInStocks is not the average though? Am I right? I'm trying to compare the average from some warehouse to a specific warehouse, if it is greater keep it else throw it away.

Comment: @In206 please give more details, we need to know about the structures of tables and some sample data and your expected result